# Why new Date set as today gives back yesterday

Tags: javascript, date

This is the first time that I get this result.

I'm using a Telerik control RadDatePicker and I'm assigning the date client-side.

The thing is that the control doesn't accept a string as date, but a Date object in javascript

So, my code to set the date in the control is

```
var radDateControl = $find("radDateControl");
radDateControl.set_selectedDate(new Date('2016-04-26'));
```

But, I realized that the new Date is returning the date as yesterday! Why?

It's 5:58pm Eastern Time (US & Canada) right now. And if I do this

```
alert(new Date('2016-04-26'));
```

I get this

```
Mon Apr 25 2016 20:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
```

Why and how can I get the day as of today.

---

**Update**

What I finally did it was this. Hope it can help others.

```
var dateAsString = "2016-04-26";
var year = dateAsString.split('-')[0];
var month = dateAsString.split('-')[1];
var day = dateAsString.split('-')[2];
var date = new Date(Date.UTC(year, month - 1, day, 0,0,0));
date.setTime(date.getTime() + date.getTimezoneOffset() * 60 * 1000);
rpdDateControl.set_selectedDate(date);
```

Comment: That date is clearly being parsed as a UTC date at midnight, hence why it seems like "yesterday" to you in your timezone of Eastern Time, as you are 4 hours behind UTC (given DST).

Comment: You can use universal time instead of the local time like this var utcDate = new Date(Date.UTC(2016, 4, 26, 0, 0, 0));

Comment: Still geting a Date object with the timezone! This is from Chrome console: new Date(Date.UTC(2016,04,26,0,0,0))
Wed May 25 2016 20:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)

Comment: @JoshLeeDucks—that will return exactly the same date as `new Date('2016-05-26')` (in conforming implementations) since "2016-05-26" should be treated as UTC (contrary to ISO 8601).

Answer (score 3):

The newly created date object is totally correct. The wrong part in here or at least the part confusing you is your browser, parsing the date object into your current timezone.

If you create a new date object and save it into a variable ...

```
var date = new Date('2016-04-26');
```

... you will get what you've asked for. A Date object representing the 26/04/2016 (in **UTC**).

Since you use your browser to get your date objects value, the value just gets parsed through your local timezone (in your case **Eastern Daylight Time**). So if you want to handle the correct date which you've used to create the new date object, you may use `.toUTCString()`.

I know, parsing timezones can be really frustrating. In order to handle different timezones, you may try out [Moment](http://momentjs.com/) or [Moment Timezone](http://momentjs.com/timezone/). I guess moment should fit your needs, but just for the completion.

Comment: It is curious. I tested what you told me in a jsfiddle and it worked, but not in my application. I'm just doing the same thing in onload event of window, but my variable date it is still yesterday! I cannot use the method toUTCString() because the control that I'm using only accepts a Date object and not a string.

Comment: Could you run the code in this fiddle on your browsers developer console? Of course, the output would be interesting. https://jsfiddle.net/os9raq9h/

Comment: Yes, it is "Tue, 26 Apr 2016 00:00:00 GMT". Even if I don't use the toUTCString it works. But in my app it doesn't. I'm using VS2012, Embeeded IIS (ASP.NET Development Server) and Chrome.

Comment: Little searching lead me to this: http://www.telerik.com/forums/raddatepicker-timezone-issue. You may try to pass the date you get from your datepicker into JavaScripts native date() function. If even that's not working, you may have to look around google to solve that. I'm sorry that I couldn't help more, didn't think that tool would have timezone issues. But as I mentioned in my answer - It really can be a mess. :)

Comment: "*…the value just gets parsed through your local timezone…*" no it doesn't. The string is parsed to get some values, that are then used to create a Date object. The values are treated as UTC. The host time zone is considered is when outputting the date values, not when creating the internal time value.

Comment: @Aer0, Thanks for your help and links to provided to manage timezones. I didn't know about them and I started to read about it. It's awesome.  I really appreciated your help.

Answer (score 0):

Just use Date.now() instead.  I'm not sure why the string isn't working but this will work anyways.

Comment: @Aer0 is right actually, but either way will work.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking date 26, but with timezone changes it gives you back 2 hours, why not just `alert(new Date());` and let it give you its current date?, also to check it go to the server using ssh and type date, if its not the date you are you can use tzselect to modify the server to your date